# QR factorization, condition number

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having a problem proving this relation:

$\frac{||\delta Q||_2/||Q||_2}{||\delta A||_2/||A||_2} \leq \kappa_2(A)$

where $A=QR$   $\ \ A+\delta A = (Q+\delta Q)R$. $Q$ and $Q+\delta Q$ are unitary and $R$ is upper triangular with positive diagonal elements. $\kappa$ is the condition # evaluated using the 2-norm.

So I know that the 2-norm of a unitary matrix is 1.

Then the above relation simplifies to:
$\frac{||\delta Q||_2||A||_2}{||\delta A||_2} \leq \kappa_2(A) = ||A||_2||A^{-1}||_2$

so all we need to prove is 
$\frac{||\delta Q||_2}{||\delta A||_2} \leq ||A^{-1}||_2$

This is the part I am stuck on. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify: is your "$2$-norm" the operator norm induced by the $2$-norm on vectors, or the Frobenius norm?.

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is the former? The 2-norm for us is the $||A||_2=\rho(A^*A)^{0.5}$ where $\rho$ is the spectral radius (i.e., maximum absolute eigenvalue)

Comment: Yes, this is the operator norm induced by the $2$-norm on vectors.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta Q = (\delta A) R^{-1}$, so $\|\delta Q\|_2 \le \|\delta A\|_2 \|R^{-1}\|_2$, i.e. $$\dfrac{\|\delta Q\|_2}{ \|\delta A\|_2 }\le \|R^{-1}\|_2$$

Now $A^{-1} = R^{-1} Q^{-1}$ and $Q^{-1}$ is unitary, so $\|A^{-1}\|_2 = \|R^{-1}\|_2$.

Comment: Thanks. I do not follow the last line. Why isn't $||A^{-1}||_2 \leq ||R^{-1}||_2$ per the same property you used in the first line?

Comment: $||A^{-1}||_2 = ||R^{-1}Q^{-1}||_2 = \rho(Q(R^{-1})^*R^{-1}Q^{-1})^{0.5}$   Oh I think I remember that $$||UA||_2=||A||_2$$ where $U$ is a unitary matrix. I even proved this before. So in our case $U=Q$ and $A=R$ Thanks! I see it now.

Comment: Oops my last comment should be $$||UA||_2 = ||A||_2 = ||AU||_2$$ and we can make use of the second equality